# MVC Azure application hangs when running under debugger

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, freeze

I have upgraded to VS2012 and MVC4. My application runs in local development environment when I run without the debugger. However when I run with the debugger it does not load the first view. The browser just hangs.

I have traced the code all thw until the View is called and then nothing happens. I don't have a problem with a clean new MVC application running under Azure emulator.
Any ideas?
Thanks
Martin

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the Model's constructor for the view. Does it reach it?

Comment: Yes. It reaches all the way to inside the view. It just does not load in the browser which shows it as "Connecting". If I  then type in the url of the action it then loads. So it is working but seems to time out on the loading. One difference to my other computer is that I am running under Windows 8 on the laptop. Not sure if this makes any difference.